# Issue with cowplots() plot_grid() causing legend and axes to squish

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, plot-grid

When I make my plots they look fine. But then when I join them together using plot_grid() from the cowplot() package, the axes labels and legend start overlapping with other aspects of the plot. Please see below image (I've covered he main plot as I don't want to share results).

Why is it doing this?

[image]

This is how I coded the cowplot. As I say the plots are fine until this point.

```
library(cowplot)
plot2 <- plot_grid(p2,p1, ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.25,1))
plot(plot2)
```